# mouseleave function fadeTo initial value (turn back)

Tags: jquery, default, mouseenter, mouseleave, fadeto

I'm doing a background player. When the user clicks the `#play` button, the main menu fade to `0.1` to not obstruct the view. But he can use the main menu at any time by passing the mouse over it and back to opacity `1`. When he removes the mouse, becomes transparent again.

When the user presses the `#pause` button, the opacity of the main menu goes back to opaque. But when he removes the mouse over from the main menu, the opacity must remains 1.

Basically I have this:

```
$("#play").click(function() {
    $("#menu").fadeTo('slow', 0.1);
    $(this).hide();
    $('#pause').show();
});

$("#pause").click(function() {
    $("#menu").fadeTo('slow', 1);
    $(this).hide();
    $('#play').show();
});

$("#menu").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#menu").fadeTo('slow', 1);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $("#menu").fadeTo( // I want this back to the initial value, which can be 0.1 or 1 );
});
```

You can see it working here:
http://luisgustavoventura.com

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ivayoz/edit#javascript,html,live)**

You can do something like this:

```
var paused = true;

$("#play").click(function() {
  paused = false;
  $("#menu").fadeTo('slow', 0.1);
  $(this).hide();
  $('#pause').show();
});

$("#pause").click(function() {
  paused = true;
  $("#menu").fadeTo('slow', 1);
  $(this).hide();
  $('#play').show();
});

$("#menu").mouseenter(function() {
  if (paused){return;}
  $("#menu").fadeTo('slow', 1);
  }).mouseleave(function(){
  if (paused){return;}
  $("#menu").fadeTo('slow', 0.1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this, just write the final value for your menu to a variable and then use that to fade the menu to it:

```
var menuopacity = 1;
$("#play").click(function() {
    menuopacity = 0.1;
    $("#menu").fadeTo('slow', menuopacity);
    $(this).hide();
    $('#pause').show();
});

$("#pause").click(function() {
    menuopacity = 1;
    $("#menu").fadeTo('slow', menuopacity);
    $(this).hide();
    $('#play').show();
});

$("#menu").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#menu").fadeTo('slow', 1);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $("#menu").fadeTo('slow', menuopacity);
});
```

Update regarding the comments:
Here's another solution that uses the actual value from the menu but this might be prone to runtime errors when the user reenters the menu while it's still fading out:

```
$("#play").click(function() {
    $("#menu").fadeTo('slow', 0.1);
    $(this).hide();
    $('#pause').show();
});

$("#pause").click(function() {
    $("#menu").fadeTo('slow', 1);
    $(this).hide();
    $('#play').show();
});

var menuopacity = 1;
$("#menu").hover(function() {
    menuopacity = $("#menu").css('opacity');
    $("#menu").fadeTo('slow', 1);
}, function(){
    $("#menu").fadeTo('slow', menuopacity);
});
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, I'll use your solution. thank you. However, there is no property of jQuery that resembles the CSS :hover? Changing the style only with mouse over and when you take out, back to the default style without having to specify it?

Comment: No, you can use .hover(in, out) instead of mouseenter and mouseleave but in the end it's just another way of writing it.